# Vagaries of perception meaning

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, phrase-request

What is the definition of "Vagaries of perception"? 
 The way I interpret it: twisted reality vision / wrong reality check.

Am I correct? I know it appeared in the Matrix movie there's no need to quote it from there.

Comment: Yes, as in optical illusions, or inability to hear. I.E., you can always believe what you perceive.

Comment: Please look up definitions before asking questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Vagary is defined slightly differently in different places, but perhaps most relevant is from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vagary) "an erratic, unpredictable, or extravagant manifestation, action, or notion".

With this definition, "vagaries of perception" would mean things you perceive (see, hear, etc) which are not consistent or solid, but seem to change or are unreliable or transient, and often stand out as unusual or distinctive. Perhaps a mirage, an optical illusion, [a dress you can't tell the colour of](https://www.vox.com/2015/2/27/8119901/explain-color-dress), a rainbow, or something you think you see but turns out on closer inspection to be something else.

The key meaning is that the think is not permanent or real, it's not there - it's just a temporary illusion, something you see or hear or feel that doesn't correspond with reality.